# Javascript toFixed(2) function not working

Tags: javascript, format, decimal

I am trying to get an output of 4.01 but I am getting 4.013000000000005 instead. The first time I ran the code, I thought the problem was that I didn't have parseFloat but it still doesn't run. This is the code:

```js
var num = 194.092;
var amount = 198.103;
console.log(amount - parseFloat(num.toFixed(2)));
```

Comment: try `var finalResult = amount - parseFloat(num);  console.log(finalResult.toFixed(2))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004)

Comment: This will work -
console.log((amount - num).toFixed(2));

Answer (score 0):

You need to parseFloat the result.

```js
var num =194.092;
var amount = 198.103;
console.log(parseFloat(amount - num).toFixed(2));
```